# Entity FrameWork 6.1:change migration code generation template?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I need that change clustered index to another column and I found a solution for this [change clustered index to another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096630/entity-framework-6-1-how-to-change-clustered-index-to-another-column).in my solution I must modify generated migration code like

```
.PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
```

To

```
.PrimaryKey(t => t.Id, null, true)
```

**Is there any way that I do it automatically and I don't need modify migration?**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is currently no way to do this.  See the comments in the following ADO.NET Blog post.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/02/11/ef-6-1-0-beta-1-available.aspx

Specifically:

> Rowan Miller  19 Feb 2014 3:37 PM
>
> @Cragun  & @redfearnk - At this stage you need to make the primary key
>   index non-clustered by editing migration code. You could either do
>   this by editing the scaffolded migration that creates the table to
>   specify 'clustered = false' in the Index call for the primary key, or
>   by manually adding code to change the index in a later migration.
>
> In the future we may allow you to add an Index attribute to the key
>   property to change the index that gets generated by default.